# How to check with SQL whether a column is an identity column for an Access database?

Tags: ms-access, auto-increment, identity

Knowing how to [check whether a column is an identity column for Microsoft SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/188967/how-do-i-determine-if-a-column-is-an-identity-column-in-mssql-2000), I currently still found no solution for doing the same with SQL for a Microsoft Access database.

**My question:**

How can I check with SQL whether a column is an identity column for a Microsoft Access database?

*(Since I want to do it in my code, an ADO.NET solution would be helpful, too, although [it seems, that this is not possible](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/eb845da8-6e15-41a9-8be7-3e84ae3e1fec/getoledbschematable-datatype-autonumber?forum=adodotnetdataproviders))*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a solution with DAO:

```
Dim db As DAO.Database, tbl As DAO.TableDef
Dim f As DAO.Field
Set db = CurrentDb()

For Each tbl In db.TableDefs
    If tbl.Name = "Table1" Then
        For Each f In tbl.Fields
            If f.Attributes = 17 And f.Type = 4 Then    '(17 = dbAutoIncrField (16) + dbFixedField(1),  4 = dbLong)
                MsgBox ("Table1 idenity column: " & f.Name)
            End If
        Next f
    End If
Next tbl
```

This checks, if there is a column with `Type` = 4 [`dbLong`] and an `Attributes` value of 17 (16 [`dbAutoIncrField`] + 1 [`dbFixedField`]).

This worked fine for me so far.